# Multiple issues in one, Bios Password / Linux-windows dual boot /keyboard layout has me stuck!

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, password, keyboard-layout, bios

I have a major issue. I recently bought a used laptop, Acer Aspire VA70 that has-had 2 OS (Windows 10 and Linux). I stumbled onto Linux only because Windows was so restricted that I decided to do a clean install of my Windows 10 professional edition.

But the keys are a hit and miss <kbd>G</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> are some keys missing <kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Y</kbd> are reversed.

So I tried an external keyboard, still no help. I wiped the disk as an external to my main pc and installed Win10. Now I have a `no boot device found`, when I hit <kbd>F2</kbd> for bios menu I get the `enter password`. When I hit <kbd>F12</kbd>, I get the blank list of what should be bootable devices.

The previous owner failed to tell me anything except the battery needed to be changed and doesn't know how to fix it either. I tried getting in through Rufus, but everything is `denied access` the terminal won't work all the apps turned blank.

I already took out the RTC, and did the whole jumper thing. I don't know this system, I barely got the hang of CMD in Windows 10! I seriously thought of the extreme and changing the bios chip.

Comment: This site doesn't support generic GNU/Linux or Linux, your issue appears to be mostly hardware (off-topic), though you mention windows (off-topic) or Linux (off-topic) without touching what this site is about at all.  Rants about Acer troubles are likewise off-topic, but sorry, I don't see any on-topic question (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let suppose that your HDD is ok.  Clean Linux partitions completely. (format in ext.4)  Reinstall windows10 and once windows 10 is installed, you can install Ubuntu in dual boot.

Comment: ok I will give it a try! thank you.!!

Comment: Ok you this was so easy, and it worked perfectly. Now my laptop is up and running and the only issue I'm having is the (language) keyboard. But I thank you so much for that tid bit of knowledge!

Comment: The language support for your keyboard: you have certainly remarked that I am not English native to.    Go to the terminal.
  type:  sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool   and give your password when asked,
 type:    gnome-tweaks
   go to "region and language" - (I suppose this is the wright transduction in English),   and change your inputsource  with the    +   sign . You will see what I mean . Thats it.   Julien Chau